# WMI Query based on antecedent string

Tags: windows, vbscript, wmi

I am trying to map PHYSICAL Disks to mounted partitions and even further into mounted volume letters (C:\ is mounted on partition 0 of disk 0)

First I'm using

```
 Select * from Win32_DiskDrive
```

to get the Index for all physical drives. Then I use

```
 SELECT Name FROM Win32_DiskPartition WHERE Index = " & objDiskDrive.Index
```

The name is something in the form of `Disk #0 Partition #0`.  Using this I try to run a query against `Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition`  This returns things like:

```
Antecedent: \\COMP_NAME\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #0, Partition #0"
Dependent: \\COMP_NAME\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="C:"
EndingAddress: 160039272959
StartingAddress: 1048576
```

If I could query against the antecedent string and parse out the dependent string I could get my mapping, but that is not working.  The query is invalid.  I am trying to run the following:

```
   Select * from Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition WHERE Antecedent LIKE '%Disk #0, Partition #0%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should use `ASSOCIATORS OF` statement ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384793%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to get results you need. 
So the wql expression would be:
`"ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='Disk #0, Partition #0'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"`

You could also use the same technique to get partition(s) first (with assoc class `Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition`)

There is a code snippet published by Microsoft which does exactly what you need (last one: 'detect which drive letter is associated with a logical disk partition', which I in fact based my answer on) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Hope this helps